# XSLT: <xsl:strip-space> does not work 

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a servlet filter in my application that intercepts all the incoming requests and tries to strip the whitespaces from the incoming XML and write the resulting 'clean' XML to the response. I am using XSLT to achieve this. Please see the XSLT below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this is not working as expected. The resulting XML is the same as the original XML (despite of using the <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> in the stylesheet.

Please help me getting this right.

Regards,
- Ashish

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the xslt from the original question, a `<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></xsl:template>` should do the trick.

Answer (score 19):

It is not clear what you intend to get as an output, and what you expect from `xsl:strip-whitespace` in the first place. But one thing to note is that it doesn't strip *all* whitespace, but only that which is deemed insignificant under the "usual" rules. In particular, from XSLT 1.0 spec:

> A text node is never stripped unless it contains only whitespace characters.

So, for example, this:

```
<foo>
  <bar>   </bar>
</foo>
```

will be stripped down to:

```
<foo><bar/></foo>
```

because it had 3 whitespace-only text nodes (after `<foo>` and before `<bar>`, between `<bar>` and `</bar>`, and after `</bar>` and before `</foo>`).

Note also that because you have `<xsl:output indent="yes">` in your stylesheet, it will end up being transformed to:

```
<foo>
   <bar/>
<foo>
```

in the output.

On the other hand, this:

```
<foo>
   text1
   <bar>  text2  </bar>
   text3
</foo>
```

Will not be stripped at all, because all text nodes it contains are not purely whitespace nodes.

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborate explanation Pavel. Indeed my understanding about the functionality was misplaced. 
Now, since this is not possible, is there a way to 'trim' the values of all the text nodes using XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: @Winnie - Did you ever find a solution to trimming text in copied nodes?

Comment: @MattHuggins Have you looked at the second answer?

Comment: Turns out my issue was with 0xA0 characters slipping in, which represents a non-breaking space characters.  Renders just like a 0x20 standard space to the eyes, but finally figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that by "trim" you mean "remove all whitespace immediately after opening and before closing tags", then the following additional template rules should do the trick:

```
<xsl:variable name="whitespace">&#x20;&#x9;&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:variable>

<!-- Trim all whitespace at end of string -->
<xsl:template name="trim-end">
   <xsl:param name="text"/>
   <xsl:variable name="last-char" select="substring($text, string-length($text), 1)" />
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains($whitespace, $last-char)">
       <xsl:call-template name="trim-end">
         <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text, 1, string-length($text) - 1)" />
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:call-template name="trim-start">
    <xsl:with-param name="text">
      <xsl:call-template name="trim-end">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes, I need to trim all spaces. Please help.

Comment: There are two errors in the code: Two closing  </xsl:call-template> and <xsl:param> next to the bottom