# Remove whitespace from XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, symphony-cms, removing-whitespace

I want all whitespace removed so my final code looks like a single block of text.

Here's my header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml"
doctype-public="-W3CDTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
omit-xml-declaration="yes"
encoding="UTF-8"
indent="no" />
```

which seems to work most of the time, but I am having issues. See [source](http://see.weareinto.com/3kUs)

The problematic area seems to be

```
<!-- clinical research coordinator -->
<xsl:template match="clinical-research-coordinators">

<xsl:variable name="id" select="item/@id" />
<xsl:variable name="entry" select="//people/entry[@id=$id]" />

<xsl:value-of select="$entry/display-name" />, 

clinical research coordinator, at 

<xsl:element name="a">

    <xsl:attribute name="href">mailto:<xsl:value-of select="$entry/email" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">email</xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:value-of select="$entry/email" />

</xsl:element>

or 

<xsl:value-of select="$entry/phone" />  

</xsl:template>
```

I am using Symphony CSM to generate the data. I just want all whitespace removed, but I want to keep my indentation patterns for readability.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT: <xsl:strip-space> does not work ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134318/xslt-xslstrip-space-does-not-work)

Comment: I disagree, this is unique, I don't want to use stip-space

Comment: There is a followup question related to this post here http://see.weareinto.com/3klB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problematic area seems to be

```
<!-- clinical research coordinator -->
<xsl:template match="clinical-research-coordinators">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="item/@id" />
    <xsl:variable name="entry" select="//people/entry[@id=$id]" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$entry/display-name" />,   clinical research coordinator, at   
    <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">mailto:
            <xsl:value-of select="$entry/email" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">email</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="$entry/email" />
    </xsl:element>
      or   
    <xsl:value-of select="$entry/phone" />
</xsl:template>
```

**The solution is**:

```
<!-- clinical research coordinator -->
<xsl:template match="clinical-research-coordinators">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="item/@id" />
    <xsl:variable name="entry" select="//people/entry[@id=$id]" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$entry/display-name" />,   clinical research coordinator, at <xsl:text/>  
    <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">mailto:
            <xsl:value-of select="$entry/email" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">email</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="$entry/email" />
    </xsl:element>
      <xsl:text> or </xsl:text>   
    <xsl:value-of select="$entry/phone" />
</xsl:template>
```

**Do note**: The use of the [**`<xsl:text>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Creating-Text) instruction to eliminate existing whitespace characters and to explicitly specify what text exactly should be output.

Comment: Great! +1 - - Now my only issue is reading the MARKDOWN formatting as objects to remove its' whitespace too http://see.weareinto.com/3kJf

Comment: @Kirk Strobeck: You cannot yet upvote, but you can accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip

> After the tree for a source document
>   or stylesheet document has been
>   constructed, but before it is
>   otherwise processed by XSLT, some text
>   nodes are stripped. A text node is
>   never stripped unless it contains only
>   whitespace characters.

This

```
",

clinical research coordinator, at

"
```

and

```
"
or

"
```

are not white space only text nodes, then they shouldn't be striped from the stylesheet.

That is why the `xsl:text` instruction is for. Use:

```
<xsl:text>, clinical research coordinator, at </xsl:text>
```

and

```
<xsl:text> or </xsl:text>
```

Comment: +1 thank you! I am commenting on the other answer, there's one last part to the problem.

Comment: @Kirk Strobeck: I think that is a different question.

Comment: @Kirk Strobeck: I don't understand what is the remainding question?

Comment: @Alejandro it was an accident, meant to put the bounty on another question :\

Comment: @Kirk Strobeck: Then you can flag for moderators attention (Jeff Atwood [quote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/why-cant-we-close-questions-with-bounties/27103#27103))