# Which one of the following options would be correct when <xsl:strip-space> is implemented?

Tags: xml, xslt

so I'm a beginner to XML and just recently received a quick introduction to XSLT. My teacher just gave me this question:

> Given this XML code, what would xsl:strip-space do if implemented in
> an XSL that is linked to the XML?
>
> ```
> <foo>
>  <bar>   </bar>
> </foo>
> ```

Then he gave these three choices to choose from:

```
<foo><bar/></foo>
```

and

```
<foo>
  <bar/>
</foo>
```

and

```
<foo><bar></bar></foo>
```

I'm leaning heavily towards the 3rd option, but I'm still hesitated because the other options look kind of correct to me too. Is number 3 the only correct option in this case or is there more to it?

Comment: check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134318/xslt-xslstrip-space-does-not-work

Comment: FIY, the first and the last options are semantically identical and the choice between them has nothing to do with `xsl:strip-space`. And since we don't know if your stylesheet is set to indent its output (not to mention any other instructions it may contain), we cannot predict the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three results of transforming your input using three different stylesheets - all of which contain the same template and the instruction:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

**XSLT #1**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result #1**

```
<foo><bar/></foo>
```

**XSLT #2**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result #2**

```
<foo>
   <bar/>
</foo>
```

**XSLT #3**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result #3**

```
<foo><bar></bar></foo>
```

---

*These results were produced using Saxon 6.5.5. Different processors may produce different results.*

---

***-- Additional clarification --***

I should add that my answer above is concerned with the expected **output** of the transformation. However, the `xsl:strip-space` instruction is implemented on the **input** to the transformation - **before** any other processing takes place. And it is important to remember that the input to the transformation is a **tree** - not a lexical representation of the tree.

IOW, if the original input tree is:

[image]

then after applying:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

the input tree will be:

[image]

This input tree can be represented equally well by:

```
<foo><bar/></foo>
```

or by:

```
<foo><bar></bar></foo>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. In all three examples, the whitespace is stripped from the input; but the second example puts new whitespace into the output as a result of indent="yes". Your presentation also confused me in that (1,2,3) are intended to number the examples, not to identify versions of XSLT.

Comment: @MichaelKay My purpose was not to answer the question but to show that it cannot be answered without additional information. I have edited the titles to make them (hopefully) less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it depends on what `xsl:strip-space` actually says. If it says `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` then the input is equivalent to `<foo><bar/></foo>`, which in turn is equivalent to `<foo><bar></bar></foo>`.

If it said `<xsl:strip-space elements="foo"/>` or `<xsl:strip-space elements="bar"/>` then space stripping would be more selective.

Also, this assumes there isn't a competing `<xsl:preserve-space>` declaration elsewhere in the stylesheet.

There are some circumstances in which whitespace will not be stripped even if you say `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`. For example: if there is an `xml:space="preserve"` attribute in scope, or if there is a schema that defines element `bar` to be of type `xs:string`.