# How to keep XSLT from introducing whitespaces in HTML output

Tags: html, xslt, whitespace

I am generating HTML from XML sources using XSLT. The HTML shows a lot of whitespace that was not in the original XML files. Normally this is not a problem as the browser will ignore the extra whitespace characters. But I am developing an application that relies on correct positioning of the text cursor inside the HTML page. The added whitespaces do mess up the offsets, making it impossible to reliably position the cursor inside an element.

My question: how can I get my XSLT to not introduce any additional whitespaces in text nodes? I am using <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> but that does not keep the processor from introducing lots of whitespace. It looks like some pretty-printing processing is applied to the HTML and I have no idea where this comes from. I am currently using Saxon PE 9.9.1.7

[Edit]

I created a simple example that shows the same strange behaviour. First the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <p>This is a long sentence. Trying to reproduce a whitespace handling problem with XSLT. This manual describes the spacecraft, safety aspects, usage and maintenance procedures. Make sure the manual is available to anyone who will be using the product.</p>
</root>
```

Here is the simplified XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;&#xD;</xsl:text>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                <script src="cursor.js"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p contenteditable="true" id="p1" onclick="show_position()">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The JavaScript file to show the current cursor position:

```
function show_position( )
{
    alert('position: ' + document.getSelection().anchorOffset );
}
```

The HTML that is generated by the XSLT looks like this (shown in oXygen):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p contenteditable="true" id="p1" onclick="show_position()">This is a long sentence. Trying to reproduce a whitespace handling problem with XSLT.
         This manual describes the spacecraft, safety aspects, usage and maintenance procedures.
         Make sure the manual is available to anyone who will be using the product.</p><script src="cursor.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Viewing the HTML in a browser makes all the extra whitespaces collapse into a single space, as expected. Clicking inside the paragraph shows the current offset from the start of the paragraph. Clicking immediately before 'This manual' shows position 86. Clicking one character to the right shows position 96. The same extra whitespace is introduced in the sentence starting with 'Make sure'.

I tried with Chrome and Safari - both show identical results. It does not seem to be a browser problem, but an issue with HTML generation by the XSLT processor. I have tried other Saxon versions but the resulting HTML is always the same.

Any further info on how to prevent these extra whitespace characters in my HTML output would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This answer explains, how `strip-space` works in-depth: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134318/xslt-xslstrip-space-does-not-work Is that relevant to your problem?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I will try to create a reproducible example. The current source and XSLT are much too large to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for `output method="html"` is `indent="yes"`, I think, so you could certainly explicitly set `indent="no"` on your `xsl:output` declaration.

Additionally, as you say you use Saxon PE 9.9, you have access to XSLT 3 features like `suppress-indentation="p"` and/or Saxon PE/EE specific settings to use a very high setting for the normal line length, check the documentation for e.g. `saxon:line-length` or similar.

Comment: That works. I have never seen this option. IMHO the default should have been 'no'. But it does work now, so I am happy with your answer. About using XSLT 3: the final XSL will have to work on a hosted domain, which unfortunately allows nothing beyond XSL 1.

Comment: "I have never seen this option". That sounds as if you are learning by example: you're missing an awful lot of features that the technology can offer if you only ever use constructs that you've seen other people use. Do some reading!

Comment: @MichaelKay - I would love to read up on all the XSLT options and I have started but not yet finished reading your XPath and XSLT 2 book. Unfortunately, XSLT is only one of the technologies I need to use and there are only 24 hours in a day. On the other hand, I am constantly inventing stuff that nobody else has tried before. Hard stuff is sometimes easier for me than the basics - a true philosopher, right ?

Comment: I know the problem. There are plenty of technologies I have to use with only a superficial understanding - gradle is a current example. But I would go to a reference book before I went to StackOverflow for help on that.